# How to echo forward slash in PHP having content-type set to application/javascript

Tags: javascript, php

```
<?php
header("Content-type: application/javascript");

echo json_encode(array("reply" => "SERVER CRIED" , "Tip" => "Remove the part following '/' in URL")) ; //If params not provided.

?>
```

it will echo this:-

```
{"reply":"SERVER CRIED","Tip":"Remove the part following '\/' in URL"}
```

but I want it to echo this:-

```
{"reply":"SERVER CRIED","Tip":"Remove the part following '/' in URL"}
```

Comment: Use `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES`, but really it's no problem and you shouldn't need to worry about it.

Comment: Also it's `application/json`, not `application/javascript`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.You need to Use `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES` for your purpose, but it's not going to create any problem what you have already.

2.It's `application/json`, not `application/javascript`

Check below code:-

```
<?php
header("Content-type: application/json");

echo json_encode(array("reply" => "SERVER CRIED" , "Tip" => "Remove the part following '/' in URL"),JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES) ; //If params not provided.

?>
```

Output:-https://eval.in/839467

Answer (score 3):

Use JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES

```
<?php
header("Content-type: application/javascript");

echo json_encode(array("reply" => "SERVER CRIED" , "Tip" => "Remove the part following '/' in URL"), JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES) ; //If params not provided.

?>
```

See the options section here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Info on JSON constants here:
http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php